# Make Different variables in a loop in python

Tags: python, variables

I want to make variables inside a for loop like this :

```
for i in range(1,4):
        qi = i
```

the answer I want is that :

```
q1 = 1
q2 = 2
q3 = 1
```

How can I do that in python ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to just use a list:

```
q = range(1, 4)
```